# Updating existing security group using heat

Tags: openstack, heat

I have crated  a few security groups using CLI in my OpenStack tenant. I tried to update the security group rules using Heat for these groups. But instead of update, a new security group got created. Is there a way I can update the security group in these rules using Heat?

Answer (score 1):

If security groups are created via Heat stack-create then those resource id's will be maintained by HEAT. In such a case, security groups can be updated with the new set of rules by stack-update option in Heat.

Answer (score 1):

Resources not created by a heat stack can't be managed by Heat. Since security group with rules is a resource by itself, an existing security group can't simply be updated via Heat. You have to create the security group in Heat too.

For most use cases, you can simply create a new security group as part of your heat-stack and use that for VMs created in that heat-stack.